# What is the equivalent of UserHostAddress in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext

What is the equivalent in ASP.NET Core of ASP.NET Framework's `HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress`?

I tried `this.ActionContext.HttpContext` but cannot find the `UserHostAddress` nor the `ServerVariables` properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get client IP address in ASP.NET CORE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you have access to the `HttpContext`, you can get the Local/Remote IpAddress from the `Connection` property like so:

```
var remote = this.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
var local = this.HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress;
```

Answer (score 20):

This has moved since [Badrinarayanan's answer in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132908/what-is-the-equivalent-of-userhostaddress-in-asp-net-core/27133253#27133253) was posted. Access it now via

```
httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress
```

Comment: This is always `null` for me. (I deploy the website on IIS on a VM)

Answer (score 16):

`HttpRequest.UserHostAddress` gives the IP address of the remote client. In ASP.NET Core 1.0, you have to use  the HTTP connection feature to get the same. `HttpContext` has the `GetFeature<T>` method that you can use to get a specific feature. As an example, if you want to retrieve the remote IP address from a controller action method, you can do something like this.

```
var connectionFeature = Context
           .GetFeature<Microsoft.AspNet.HttpFeature.IHttpConnectionFeature>();

if (connectionFeature != null)
{
    string ip = connectionFeature.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works, I would have never arrived to this myself. 
Where I could find a documentation o some reference? I`m also searching the old HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

Do you know what is the new syntax to this?
Thanks!

Comment: This appears to not work correctly when running in IIS 8. The IP address returned in the code is different than what IIS outputs in the request log. Any updates to this that would allow it to work properly in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core RC1-update1 I found IP (with port) in `X-Forwarded-For` header, whose value can be accessed from a controller as:

```
HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: This header is typically only present if the request went through a load balancer (or something similar) to add the original address.