# RemoteIpAddress is always null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

```
var test1 = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>();
var test2 = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

When running the application locally on *IISExpress*, these two lines correctly return the value `0:0:1`.

When I publish the application on *IIS 7.5* (which is running on a VM). `RemoteIpAddress` is always `null`

I am using *ASP.Net 5 RC 1*.

How can I get the client's IP address in an *ASP.NET 5* application ?

I tried the solutions in the following questions, however I have the problem mentioned above:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132908/userhostaddress-in-asp-net-5-vnext)

Comment: The X-Forwarded-For appears to be set by default in RC1 U1 from this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36316189/538763)

Answer (score 13):

What you're seeing is accurate, if not useful. Connections termination at IIS, which then forwards to Kestrel, the v.next web server, so connections to the web server are indeed from localhost.

What you need to do is enable support for X-Forwarded-For

1. Add the `Microsoft.AspNet.HttpOverrides` package
2. In your `Configure()` method add

   ```
       app.UseOverrideHeaders(new OverrideHeaderMiddlewareOptions
       {
           ForwardedOptions = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | 
                              ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
       });
   ```

Note that this package will change in RC2 to make it safer to use.

Comment: Still getting null. Apparently this is due to a bug: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/17#issuecomment-184855218

Comment: Ah darn. Move to IIS8? *grin*

Comment: The nuget package is now **Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides** and the configure method is: **app.UseForwardedHeaders(...)**

Answer (score 12):

In `ASP.NET Core 2.0` project you need to add package [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides/) and add this code to your `Configure` method:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because of you are trying to connect from localhost. If you have another computer in same LAN, try to connect with this pc but use user ip instead of localhost.