# Validate IP from request against claim in JWT authentication token

Tags: c#, authentication, token, jwt, .net-core

I'm developing a .Net Core Web API using JWT authentication (like [here](https://goblincoding.com/2016/07/24/asp-net-core-policy-based-authorisation-using-json-web-tokens/)).

I added a new Claim to store the ip adrress of the request, and then, I want to check it on each consecutive request to validate that the ip address source of the request is the same ip that originally requested the token.

To do that i made a Custom Policy-Based Authentication (like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies)), and i want to get the ip of each request on the AuthorizationHandler of the policy, but i can't get it ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core) didn't work on AuthorizationHandler).

Maybe that's not the way to do that I want, can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you trust the JWT and need this additional authentication within your service?

Comment: Because if someone steals the token, i do not want that can use from another ip. Maybe JWT have something to mitigate this and I didn't know. Thanks @thoean

Comment: It sounds like a too simplistic approach to a highly complex problem. I assume you encrypt everything through HTTPS as a baseline, and follow other practices to prevent attacks like XSS etc. This is an interesting article to get started: https://auth0.com/forum/t/stealing-jwt-from-authenticated-user/352/12

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'll read that link. Thanks.

Comment: Even I am thinking of IP verification. Reason being I am exposing my API to limited source and they should not use it outside the allowed premises. I don't know if it is a good idea but would work for at lease few attackers.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic, there's nothing wrong, but it's increaing your operational overhead, for example, to manage a client's IP. Also, why should a service know the client's IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end what I did was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41335628/5326387) to get the IP.

Then I add an `ActionFilterAttribute` overrideing `OnActionExecuting`

In that filter I get the original IP from the Claims and compare it with the request IP (`context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`).