# How to get username of requesting user not app pool under windows auth

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

Using Blazor server app.

I have the app pool running as a domain account, but I need the user name doing the request.
When using this, I get the name of the app pool instead.

```
CallingUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split(new char[] { '\\' })[1];
```

**Update**
This post helped me
[Get Current User in a Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264657/get-current-user-in-a-blazor-component/60377744#60377744)

Also, needed to yet enable Websockets in IIS.  Didn't discover that until I published to a test server.

Comment: any update? Does my reply answer your questions?

Comment: It was helpful, as I seen your approach mentioned in several other sources.  However, I ended up using an approach listed inanother post.  See update above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the login user in the sever side. You should make the service as scope and then you could inject the `AuthenticationStateProvider` into service.

Then you could get the current login user.

Details, you could refer to below codes:
public class WeatherForecastService
{
private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

```
     public WeatherForecastService(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider) {

        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }

public string GetCurrentUserName() {
      var provider=  _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        return provider.Result.User.Identity.Name;
    
    } 
 }
```

---

As far as I know, if you want to get the current login user, you could try to use AuthenticationStateProvider service.

The built-in [AuthenticationStateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.authorization.authenticationstateprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1) service obtains authentication state data from ASP.NET Core's HttpContext.User.

You could inject the `AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider` and then use `AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync` to get the user state, at last ,you could use `user.Identity.Name` to get the current user name.

More details ,you could refer to below codes:

```
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider


<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<hr />
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetUserName">Click me</button>

<p>Current Login User = @Username</p>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    private string Username = string.Empty;
    private async Task GetUserName()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        Username = user.Identity.Name;

    }

}
```

Result:

[image]