# How would I dynamically set the allowed Role or Policy for an Authorize View tag or attribute in Blazor from appsettings?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I am attempting to make a shared layout for a few applications. These applications are Blazor server-side apps. This layout has a small menu that can be configured via the appsettings file. One of the requirements is that we are able to show or hide certain menu items based on a list of Active Directory Groups in the appsettings. Below is an example of the JSON settings.

```
{
  "MenuItemName":"Protected Menu Item",
  "AllowedGroups": ["Administrator", "SpecialGroup", "SpecialGroup2"]
}
```

I believe we need to use either an <AuthorizeView> tag and/or an [Authorized] attribute on the page to ensure uses can't navigate to the page.

How would I actually dynamically fill in those tags? For example, take the following examples from the Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorize-attribute-1). How would I replace the Roles="admin, superuser" with settings from within my Appsettings.json?

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="admin, superuser">
    <p>You can only see this if you're an admin or superuser.</p>
</AuthorizeView>
```

In another example using the [Authorized] attribute how would I dynamically populdate the Roles = "admin, superuser" section from the appsetings?

```
@page "/"
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "admin, superuser")]

<p>You can only see this if you're in the 'admin' or 'superuser' role.</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup a policy to do it :
This just reads a string array from `"AllowedGroups"` in `appsettings.json` but it demonstrates the fundamentals.

```
{
  "AllowedGroups": [ "Administrator", "Moderator" ]
}
```

```
public class HasRolesFromConfigRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    internal string[] allowedGroups;
    public HasRolesFromConfigRequirement(string[]? allowedGroups) => this.allowedGroups = allowedGroups;
}
public class HasRolesFromConfigHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasRolesFromConfigRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        HasRolesFromConfigRequirement requirement)
    {
        var rolesRequired = requirement.allowedGroups;
        if (rolesRequired is null)
        {
            context.Fail();
        }
        else
        {
            var hasRequiredRole = rolesRequired.Where(role => context.User.IsInRole(role)).Any();
            if(hasRequiredRole)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

```
public static class AuthorizationOptionsPolicyExtensions
{
    public static void AddPolicies(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, HasRolesFromConfigHandler>();
        services.AddAuthorizationCore(options => options.ConfigurePolicies(configuration));
    }

    public static AuthorizationOptions ConfigurePolicies(this AuthorizationOptions options, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var localConfiguration = configuration.Get<LocalConfiguration>();
        options.AddPolicy("HasARequiredRole", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasRolesFromConfigRequirement(localConfiguration.AllowedGroups)));
        return options;
    }

}
```

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="HasARequiredRole">
    <div>
        Has A Required Role
    </div>
</AuthorizeView>
```

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "HasARequiredRole")]
...
```

```
[Authorize(Policy = "HasARequiredRole")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

A .net6(rc1) [repo](https://github.com/BrianLParker/DynamicRolesPolicy).

I would personally look at claim based permissions. This way you can assign application resources to a claim. Then dynamically assign the claims to roles or individuals.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are embedded in the assembly at **build time**. Once the project/DLL is built, you **cannot** change the value again.

You need to perform **runtime** authorization. Since you're trying to check roles, inject the configuration and check if the user has any of the roles:

```
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
```

```
var isAllowed = Configuration.GetSection("AllowedGroups")
    .Get<string[]>()
    .Any(group => user.IsInRole(group));
```

### Further info

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#procedural-logic-1
- [Get Current User in a Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264657/get-current-user-in-a-blazor-component)

Comment: That makes sense to me. Using this runtime authorization I am able to remove the menu items from the list however the user can still navigate to the route and get into the page. I am not entirely sure what I could do to ensure they can't access those pages.

Do I do a check for that role/group during the component initialization and simply throw an error or text to say they aren't allowed? Or would there be a better method of restricting access for that page?

Comment: That's called `route guard` in other frameworks like vue/react etc. Maybe hook into `OnInitialized` and redirect to unauthorized page if the user is not authorized?