# If I'm developing a Blazor Server Side App with Windows Authentication, how can I get the logged-in user's picture?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication, claims, system.security

[@Ogglas stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65853649/109941):

If you create a new project and choose Blazor with Windows Authentication you get a file called `Shared\LoginDisplay.razor` with the following content:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
</AuthorizeView>
```

My Question:

- How can I add the logged-in user's **picture** to this component?

Comment: The page is HTML.  So add like following : https://www.canto.com/blog/insert-image-html/?force_isolation=true#:~:text=Copy%20and%20paste%20your%20image,parameters%20prefaced%20by%20a%20src.

Comment: @jdweng HTML is not my problem. How can I use the Active Directory picture to inform the `img` tag's `src` attribute?

Comment: What claims can you see in `HttpContext.User`?

Comment: What you posted is the Authorize tag inside html data.  You need to add the picture just like any other html tag

Comment: @jdweng Again - The HTML is not my issue.