User authorization in Blazor
I have a problem with the method that authorizes users
  private async Task LogUsername()
  {
      var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
      var user = authState.User;


      if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
          LoggedUserCode = user.Identity.Name;
      }
  }

Method call:
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        await LogUsername();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LoggedUserCode))
            user1.Id = Authentication.UserAccountService._users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Kod == LoggedUserCode).Id;
        element = await Task.Run(() => adminPanels.GetUser(user1.Id));
        mg = await Task.Run(() => wS.GetWarehouse(element.magazyn));
        // okuciaObj = await Task.Run(() => VikkingOkucia.PobierzOkucia(mg.id));
        _table?.SetEditingItem(null);
    }

but after refreshing the browser I have only nulls in the values ​​and dapper crashes.
CustomAuthentitactionStateProvider.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace VikkingWebApp.Authentication
{
    public class CustomAuthentitactionStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage;
        private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

        public CustomAuthentitactionStateProvider(ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage)
        {
            _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
        }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var userSessionStorageResoult = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<UserSession>("UserSession");
                var userSession = userSessionStorageResoult.Success ? userSessionStorageResoult.Value : null;
                if (userSession == null)
                    return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.UserCode),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.Role)
                }, "CustomAuth"));
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
            }
            catch
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
            }

        }

        public async Task UpdateAuthenticactionState(UserSession userSession)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

            if (userSession != null)
            {
                await _sessionStorage.SetAsync("UserSession", userSession);
                claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.UserCode),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.Role)
                    }));
            }
            else
            {
                await _sessionStorage.DeleteAsync("UserSession");
                claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
            }

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
        }
    }
}

Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<ProtectedSessionStorage>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthentitactionStateProvider>();

I see that it is only called once  public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
and after refreshing the browser it is not called at all.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264657/get-current-user-in-a-blazor-component

finally, one line of code was missing @attribute [Authorize(Roles ="")]
and I changed the method to:
 private async Task LogUsername()
 {
     var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

     var user = authState.User;


     if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         LoggedUserCode = user.Identity.Name;
          user1 = Authentication.UserAccountService._users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Kod == LoggedUserCode);

     }

 }

