# Blazor: Injected service data are fine during prerender but disappears during second load

Tags: blazor, http-post, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

I'm running component rendering as ServerPrerender.  Using .Net 7.
I've put my HTTP Post data into scoped service that I'm injecting into a Razor component.  During prerender the data is read fine from this service but when the OnInitializedAsync is called again the values from the service are null.

*If I change the component rendring to Server the values are always null.*

I've searched this site but been unable to solve this.

I've got a Form in a page that does a POST to a Razor component page that should read the values and get data based on them.

**Edit1:**
My code is based on the answer here:
[How to use Form data received from a POST request in Blazor pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72147911/how-to-use-form-data-received-from-a-post-request-in-blazor-pages)

I've a _Host.cshtml that has a Model where I'm reading the form data in OnPostAsync into a scoped service.
This service is then injected into my .razor component where I'm trying to read the data within.

**Edit 2:**
_Host.cshtml

```
@model HostPageModel
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
or
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```

HostPageModel

```
// postFormService is injected by the DI
public HostPageModel(PostFormService postFormService)
{
    PostFormService = postFormService;
}

private PostFormService PostFormService { get; }

public async Task OnPostAsync()
{
    // store the post form in the PostFormService
    PostFormService.Form = Request.Form;
}
```

MyRazor.razor

```
@inject PostFormService PostFormService
@code {
  var loginUserId = PostFormService.Form?["LoginUserId"];
}
```

**Edit 3:**
I've also tried this approach but haven't been able to get any data passed to my Razor component.
_Host.csthml (The Model.FormGuid is being set by OnPost of the model)

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { FormGuid = Model.FormGuid }))
```

App.razor (The Guid gets printed fine)

```
<div>@this.FormGuid</div>
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <h3>Not authorized</h3>
                    <Saga.Presentation.Web.Core.Pages.RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <p>Logging in...</p>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Page not found.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code{
    [Parameter] 
    public Guid FormGuid { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    => this.FormDataService.GetFormData(FormGuid);
}
```

Component.razor (The FormGuid is null here)

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter] public Guid FormGuid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you pls at least provide necessary code snippets here so that we could troubleshoot the issue via your code.

Comment: Is this Blazor?  The code doesn't look like it.  The form, the model and the logic normally all live in the component.

Comment: Yes, this is a server side Blazor project

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis How did you pass the FormGuid to the Razor component in your answer in the linked SO question?

Comment: For some reason  
`[CascadingParameter] public Guid FormGuid { get; set; } `
in my Razor component is always null

Comment: That was a while ago!  Where is your `[CascadingParameter] public Guid FormGuid { get; set; }`?  It should be in `App,razor`.  The other code in `App` gets the form data from the singleton service and loads it into the scoped service for components to use.

Comment: I've updated my question with more code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this to work by following what the question author did here: [Blazor Server: Issue with scoped service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752175/blazor-server-issue-with-scoped-service)

In short

1. Add a property to my Data Service called FormData which holds the data to be used in the Razor pages.
2. I create the data object in the Model class of the _Hosts.cshtml file.
   In my case I'm reading HTTP POST data so I've got a OnPostAsync() method where I'm reading the values from Request.Form.
3. I pass that object to App.razor by adding "param-FormData" to the component render

< component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" param-FormData="@Model.FormData" >

4. Created the FormData property in App.razor with the [Parameter] attribute 
   [Parameter]
   public FormData FormData { get; set; } = new();
5. In OnIntialized in App.razor I set the data property of the injected service

   FormDataService.AddFormData(FormData);

Now I can inject the service into any other Razor component and get the values.

```
@inject FormDataService FormDataService
```