# What is the correct and reliable way to retrieve HttpContext in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side, httpcontext, .net-8.0

Let's consider a simple blazor app (the standard template) in which i need to have some info about the user which is connected, like:

- SessionID
- IpAddress
- User Identity Name

Usually, I retrieve this informations from HttpContext.
In particular, I follow this steps:

1. adding in the startup

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

2. injecting the service in the blazor component

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor hca
```

3. printing info

```
<p> SessionID: @hca.HttpContext?.Connection?.Id </p>
<p> IP: @hca.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress </p>
<p> User: @hca.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name </p>
```

This approach still works, also in NET6+ (using NET8), but it's marked as wrong and not recommended in the official guide. ([ref 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor)) ([ref 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/interactive-server-side-rendering?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components))

---

**Limitation - NULL HttpContext if LongPolling transport mode**

If the transport mode fallback from WebSockets to LongPolling, the HttpContext is null.
You can easily test this, forcing LongPolling transport mode in the startup

```
app.MapBlazorHub(opt =>
{
    opt.Transports =
            //Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.WebSockets |
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
});
```

This is not new ([ref 3](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39485)).

Note that on some Blazor app I'm forced to use LongPolling since WebSocket are not supported before IIS8 - WinServer2012 and/or blocked by reverse proxy which can't be changed due to corps policy.

Another approach used by someone, also included in the official guide, is capturing the HttpContext "at the startup" and then cascading it.

> The recommended approach for passing request state to the Blazor app is through root component parameters during the app's initial rendering

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538318/how-to-use-the-httpcontext-object-in-server-side-blazor-to-retrieve-information). It seems that with this approach we can also cover the LongPolling case.

---

**Limitation - single non-routable Blazor component instantiated from js**

Now let's complicate the case a bit more. I have a NET8 non-blazor web app. I added a single [non-routable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/integration?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-non-routable-components-in-pages-or-views) blazor component [instantiated from js](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/blazor/components/js-spa-frameworks?view=aspnetcore-8.0#render-razor-components-from-javascript)

1. declaring the component in the startup

```
        builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
            .AddInteractiveServerComponents(options =>  
            {
                options.DetailedErrors = true;
                options.RootComponents.RegisterForJavaScript<SchedaWeb>(identifier: "scheda-web");
            });
```

2. initializing the component from javascript

```
  Blazor.start()
      .then(function () {
          Blazor.rootComponents.add(_this.renderScheda[0], 'scheda-web', {
              id: id,
          })
      });
```

In this situation I don't have any "root component": no App, no _Host.
Can't apply the above solution. How should I retrieve the HttpContext using LongPolling?

---

**Limitation - HttpContext not reliable**

There are many other articles, also in SignalR thread (on which Blazor is based), that mention the non reliability of HttpContext ([ref 4](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14974))

Based on the official documentation, we should

> For scenarios where the HttpContext is required in interactive components, we recommend flowing the data via persistent component state from the server. For more information, see Server-side ASP.NET Core Blazor additional security scenarios.

---

Can someone explain what is the right way to reliably obtain HttpContext in all edge cases (with LongPolling transport mode, with Blazor integrated in a standard app, without having root App or _Host)?

Comment: from ClaimsPrincipal you can extract only UserIdentityName or am I wrong? I also need IpAddress and SessionID. I need to save and use this info also if user is not logged in or registered

Comment: When you write a (pseudo) SPA you simply don't have a HttpContext. _Host (or Blazor 8 SSR) is the only place to get it.

Comment: It's ok to not have HttpContext, but at least I would like to have the equivalent of it (to retrieve IpAddress and SessionID). If I use Blazor 8 without _Host, since Blazor components are instantiated from js, I don't know what to do

Answer (score -6):

This works to get the user visiting the page in a Service Side Rendered page. It's not the http request you get, but the user.

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider authProvider
```

Then in the code you do

```
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationState myAuthState = await authProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var userName = myAuthState.User.Identity.Name;
        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Masters")) {
            // Do the thing
        }
    }
}
```

In a Server Static page, you can use

```
@code
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext context { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        visitors.AddOrUpdateVisitor(context.Request, context.Response);
    }
}
```