# When is ASP.NET Core's HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-core-middleware

One uses `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` to get a client's IP address.

[`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ConnectionInfo.RemoteIpAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.connectioninfo.remoteipaddress) is marked as [nullable](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.14/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/ConnectionInfo.cs#L24).

It [will be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441521/remoteipaddress-is-always-null) when behind a reverse proxy server. (In that case the [`UseForwardedHeaders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx#use-a-reverse-proxy-server) middleware must be used.)

The docs linked above just say *"Can be null"* - under what other conditions can it be null?

Comment: See [response at the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40191). Maybe someone can add a proper answer below to explain the details described there. Basically it's for edge cases.