# How to get a client's computer name in asp.net core

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I've tried with

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()).ToString();
```

but that didn't work.
I've also tried to use

```
PCName = Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).HostName;
```

but this seems to be deprecated for Core

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444592/determine-clients-computer-name)?

Comment: On the LAN, right?

Comment: @M12Bennett i had previously stumbled on that page but i can't seem to find the namespaces for those methods

Comment: Which method are you referring to?

Comment: @M12Bennett Request.UserHostName;
comppNameHelper;
also IPAddress and IPHostEntry

i have included the following namespaces in my controller 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web;

Comment: Click on `IPAddress`, press `Ctrl`+`.`, import the namespace it suggests.

Comment: @john than you for the tip, i didnt't know about that and it looks really helpful, sadly there is no namespace suggestion for `Request.UserHostName` and `comppNameHelper`. None of the Other suggestions i get seem to work

Comment: `Request.UserHostName` is `Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` in ASP.Net Core. `CompNameHelper` is the static class in which you've placed the `DetermineCompName` method. You'll have to call it according to wherever you've placed it. It's worth noting that no method (except client participation) is likely to give you the client hostname except where the client is on the LAN.

Comment: @john this application should mostly work on a LAN, if you have better ideas to get a semi-unique identifier from a client without making them log in i'm all ears. Im not sure what you mean for where i placed `DetermineCompName` , i never did such thing

Comment: The method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445109/3181933) is called `DetermineCompName`, is it not?

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Net;

Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress).HostName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
httpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>()["REMOTE_HOST"]
```

Works on Windows only, because [check this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852574/httprequest-userhostname-in-net-core/68975818#68975818)