# How to get HostName using JS or ASP.Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there any way I can get the client's Hostname or ComputerName/Device ?

I'm using ASP.Net Core MVC.

The purpose of this is to identify if a user is working on a specified machine or not.

Comment: You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852574/httprequest-userhostname-in-net-core/68975818#68975818),But in my point of view, It's difficult to get the hostname outside the LAN.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this one and it works

```
string hostName = Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress).HostName;
```

Comment: it works on LAN but outside the LAN (this is an intranet app (LDAP) )it throws an error

Comment: I tried using this an it also not work ` try
            {
               hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress).HostName;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                hostname = "WFH";
               
            }
           `

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello If it's an intranet app why are you concerned about it not working outside the intranet?

Comment: @MahmoudHefny This does not work for me when deployed to an IIS web server in my intranet environment (with Windows authentication enforced).