# Get SessionID and UserHostAddress in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In normal asp.net, we can get the value of this by giving:

```
UserSessionID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
IPAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

How can we get the same in .Net Core. Can anyone help?

Comment: what version of .net?

Comment: Version is .Net core 3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UserHostAddress in Asp.net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132908/userhostaddress-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your session is setup like this:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("mysession", "mySessionValue");
```

Then you can get the Session id:

```
UserSessionID = HttpContext.Session.Id;
```

And the user host address:

```
IPAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```